# Sequence Models Word2vec

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sequence, word2vec, doc2vec

I am working on data-set with more than 100,000 records.
This is how the data looks like:

```
email_id    cust_id campaign_name
123         4567     World of Zoro
123         4567     Boho XYz
123         4567     Guess ABC
234         5678     Anniversary X
234         5678     World of Zoro
234         5678     Fathers day
234         5678     Mothers day
345         7890     Clearance event
345         7890     Fathers day
345         7890     Mothers day
345         7890     Boho XYZ
345         7890     Guess ABC
345         7890     Sale
```

I am trying to understand the campaign sequence and predict the next possible campaign for the customers.

Assume I have processed my data and stored it in 'camp'.

With Word2Vec-

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

model = Word2Vec(sentences=camp, size=100, window=4, min_count=5, workers=4, sg=0)
```

The problem with this model is that it accepts tokens and spits out text-tokens with probabilities in return when looking for similarities.

Word2Vec accepts this form of input-

```
['World','of','Zoro','Boho','XYZ','Guess','ABC','Anniversary','X'...]
```

And gives this form of output -

```
 model.wv.most_similar('Zoro')
[Guess,0.98],[XYZ,0.97]
```

Since I want to predict campaign sequence, I was wondering if there is anyway I can give below input to the model and get the campaign name in the output

My input to be as -

```
[['World of Zoro','Boho XYZ','Guess ABC'],['Anniversary X','World of 
Zoro','Fathers day','Mothers day'],['Clearance event','Fathers day','Mothers 
day','Boho XYZ','Guess ABC','Sale']]
```

Output -

```
model.wv.most_similar('World of Zoro')
[Sale,0.98],[Mothers day,0.97]
```

I am also not sure if there is any functionality within the Word2Vec or any similar algorithms which can help predicting campaigns for individual users.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that word2vec is the right approach to model your problem.

Word2vec uses two possible approaches: Skip-gram (given a target word predict its surrounding words) or CBOW (given the surrounding words predict the target word). Your case is similar to the context of CBOW, but there is no reason why the phenomenon that you want to model would respect the linguistic "rules" for which word2vec has been developed.

word2vec tends to predict the word that occurs more frequently in combination with the targeted one within the moving window (in your code: window=4). So it won't predict the best possible next choice but the one that occurred most often in the window span of the given word.

In your call to word2vec (Word2Vec(sentences=camp, size=100, window=4, min_count=5, workers=4, sg=0)) you are also using min_count=5 so the model is ignoring the words that have a frequency less than 5. Depending on your dataset size, there could be a loss of relevant information.

I suggest to give a look to forecasting techniques and time series analysis methods. I have the feeling that you will obtain better prediction using these techniques rather word2vec. (https://otexts.org/fpp2/index.html)

I hope it helps